# Cannot Start SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have been trying to start SQL Server 2017 and been getting
 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. '

Full Error:

> TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0xe, status code 0x1.
>   Reason: Error: 19101, Severity: -1, State: 0. (Params:). The error is
>   printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting.
>   Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.  Not enough storage is
>   available to complete this operation.

on the System Event:

> The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with the following
>   service-specific error:  Not enough storage is available to complete
>   this operation.

I do have enough space on all the drives, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally when I see: `The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting` it means there isn't enough memory.

This is further correlated by:

- Error `0xE` which is...
- 14 in decimal which is...
- `net helpmsg 14` which is...
- `ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY` = Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation. which is...
- > Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

Which is what is stated in the error:

> The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with the following service-specific error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

Make sure enough memory exists, the page file has space, and/or the max memory setting is set high enough.

To change the memory setting, start SQL Server from the command line or edit the startup flags using SQL Server Configuration Manager. Add `-f` for [minimal configuration startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-service-startup-options?view=sql-server-2017).